# How to access XML object in Restlet 2.0 thats wrapped inside a Representation object?

Tags: apache-flex, restlet-2.0

Hi I am developing an application with Flex for the GUI and Restlet for the webservices. I have a strange problem. I put my XML as a property on a generic object, and send it as part of a POST request. But in the Restlet webservice, this XML is irretrievable. How do I retrieve it? 
I tried initialising the received Representation object to a DomRepresentation, but thats not working. If I put the received Representation object into a Form object, then getFirstValue is returning that XML as a string!

---

I noticed that the contentType of the HTTPService was application/www-form-encoded so I set it to application/xml and its not helping either.

---

I use restlet 2.0m6 and here is the code snippet that I use -

@Post

public Representation process(Representation entity)

{

try

{

DomRepresentation dom = new DomRepresentation(entity);

Document d = dom.getDocument();

.

.

}
catch(Exception e)

{
e.printStackTrace();
}

and it throws a Null Pointer exception at the dom.getDocument() line. Which means no data actually arrived.

And my flex bit looks like this - 
var service : HTTPService = new HTTPService();
            service.method="POST";
            service.contentType="application/xml"
            service.url=url;
var token :AsyncToken = service.send(params);

where params is an XML object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer - http://vatsalad.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/how-to-handle-xml-received-as-part-of-a-post-request-in-restlet/